# DynamoDB Indexing Assistance and Getting My Data Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I preface all of this to say I’m still actively learning DynamoDB, and I think an answer to my question will help me understand a few things.

I have an analytics microservice that I’m pushing custom (internal) analytics events into a DynamoDB table. Columns in our Dynamo rows/items include data like:

- User ID
- IP Address
- Event Action
- Timestamp
- **Split Test ID**
- **Split Test Value**

One of the main questions we want to pull from this db is:

- "How many users saw split test x with values y?"

I’m struggling to understand how I should index my database to account for this kind of requests? I set up a “Keys Only” index targeting Split Test ID, and the query to gather these are fairly efficient, but it only pulls UserID and Split Test ID. Ideally I want an efficient query that returns multiple other associated values as well…

How do I achieve this? Do I need to be doing something much differently? Additionally, if any of my understanding of Dynamo, based on my explanations, sounds completely lacking in some regard, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: "sounds completely lacking in some regard" - seems to me that you want relational database functionality in a non-sql database? If so why not use just mysql?

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of DynamoDB as a schema-less database, which it obviously is. However, that does not mean that a schema is not important. Schemas in NoSQL databases are usually more important than they are in SQL databases and they are usually less straightforward.

The most important thing to determine how you will store your data is how you will access it. You will have to take into account all the ways that you will want to access your data and ensure it is possible by creating the necessary data columns and necessary indexes. In this case, if you want to know how many times two values are combined in a certain way, you could easily add a column that has these combined values (e.g., `splitId#splitValue` ) and use that in your indexes.

If you want to know more about advanced patterns and such, I advise you to watch this [pretty famous re:invent talk by Rick Houlihan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k) or to read [the DynamoDB book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53127868-the-dynamodb-book?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=KusacBYSIR&rank=1).

As a last note, I want to add that switching to a SQL server usually is not the solution. Picking NoSQL over SQL is usually based on non-functional requirements. There is a reason NoSQL databases are used in applications that require very low-latency retrieval of data in huge datasets, but as with everything, trade-offs are the name of the game.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It sounds like adding a column with combined values is what I need to try.

Comment: @Spookytheboy If you've got the time and really want to learn about NoSQL schema modeling in general and DynamoDB in specific, really have a look at the re:invent talk. It's highly recommended!